# D3 enable mouseover AFTER transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I add a d3-tip / mouseover event AFTER a transition on a histogram / bar chart?

I create a bar chart / plot:

```
canvas.call(tip);

var sampleBars = canvas.selectAll(".sampleBar")
  .data(data)
.enter().insert("rect", ".axis")
    .attr("class", "sampleBar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + 1; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .attr("width", x(data[0].dx + data[0].x) - x(data[0].x) - 1)
    .attr("height", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(2500)
    .delay(500)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });
```

I want to add:

```
sampleBars
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

And this is the tip:

```
    var tip = d3.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function(d) { 
    return "<span style='color:white'>" + d3.round((d.y * 100)) 
    + "%" + "</span>" + " infected"; })
```

So that the mouseover event occurs after the transition is complete. But I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The error is for the line:

```
.on('mouseover', tip.show)
```

I think there is a simple flaw in my logic. I seem to be confused about how these events or attributes interact with each other.

Again: I want to 'activate' the mouseover tip AFTER the transition is complete so that after the transition does its thing the tip will appear if the user puts their mouse over each bar. I have no problem creating the mouseover event and having it work on user mouseover to display the data I want, but I am having no luck with making this work with a transition of those bars.

Comment: You can use the [`transition.each("end", function)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each) method to add the event handlers after the transition.  But I don't think that's the problem here.  It sounds like you aren't defining `tip` prior to calling it, but I can't tell without full code.  Can you try to put together a [simple working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), using [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) or a similar tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding/removing events, one approach is to simply set/unset the `pointer-events` attribute so that the events don't fire when you want them suppressed.

```js
var myselection = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg').attr({height: 200, width: 200})
  .append('circle')
  .attr( {cx: 100, cy: 100, r: 0})
  .attr('pointer-events', 'none')
  .on('mouseover', function() { console.log('mouseover'); })
  .on('mouseout', function() { console.log('mouseout'); })

myselection
  .transition().duration(4000).attr('r', 100)
  .transition().attr('pointer-events', 'auto')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If you have the console window open you'll notice that mouse over/out logs nothing until the circle stops growing.

Comment: Great insight! Exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. I am still not sure where the flaw was in with what I was doing before. Insight into why? 

My transition causes the bars to grow - the mouseover shows the bar frequency (histogram). Why would turning pointer event ON after the transition and OFF during the transition work but no good if DURING transition? Thanks!